Help understand the output of dot product attention mechanism
I need help interpreting the output of my dot product attention mechanism which I have just started learning. My query vector was $(0,1,0)$, my keys were $key_1 = (0,1,0)$, $key_2 = (1,0,0)$, $key_3 = (1,0,0)$,$key_4 = (0,1,0)$. My values were $val_1 =  (1,2)$, $val_2 =  (0,3)$, $val_3 =  (4,5)$, $val_4 =  (2,2)$. I got my output of the attention mechanism as $ o = (1.6797712, 2.7190847)$. The question asks "How does the output vector relate to the four value vectors provided?". I am not sure how to answer this because I am currently thinking that the output more closely approximates the first and fourth value vectors as the output vector is the most similar to these and because the weights were higher for the first and fourth key vectors as they are the same as the query. But I feel like this is wrong or I am missing something. Could someone help my understanding?

it's a convex combination of the initial values
